# Javascript ротатор - сначала показывает вариант 1, потом сразу вариант 3 - в чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript

Вот код:

```
 var interval = setInterval('changeImage()', 5000);
 var flag = 1;

 function changeImage() {
     if (flag == 1) {
         path = 'тест';
         flag = 2;
     } else {
         if (flag == 2) {
             path = 'тест1';
             flag = 3;
         }
         if (flag == 3) {
             path = 'тест2'
             flag = 1;
         }
     }
     rotate.innerHTML = path;
```

По идее, сначала должно показываться "тест", потом тест1, потом тест2, но показывается сначала тест, потом тест2. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После:
flag = 3;
}
надо else вставить

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
(function(){
  function view( text ){
    console.log( text );
  };

  function change( ){
    state++;
    state = state % arr.length;

    view( arr[ state ] );
  };

  var state = -1,
      arr = [
        'текст1',
        'текст2',
        'текст3'
      ],
      id = setInterval( change, 5000 );

  change();
})();
```